# What is the preferred way of installing Kubernetes on AWS if resizing the cluster is a concern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, coreos

While trying to install Kubernetes on AWS, I have come across two major ways of doing things.

The first one is to use the deploy scripts that come packaged with Kubernetes to create a Kubernetes cluster on AWS. Another one is to use CoreOS based `kube-aws` tool to run a cluster.

What are the major advantages and disadvantages of the two approaches?

However, I have not been able to understand how one can resize an existing live cluster without downtime in either of the two systems.

Is there any way to deploy a resizable Kubernetes cluster on AWS using tools or scripts? Alternatively, is it even possible to resize a live cluster?
If yes, how can we do that without using a tool or a script (assuming none is available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kube-aws` tool utilizes an autoscaling group for the worker machines. You could resize this based on CloudWatch metrics like CPU/RAM, although this isn't set up by default. To scale it manually up or down, you can use the AWS console.

Comment: Is it not same with the default Kubernetes install? I think if the master dies on this one, autoscaling won't help.

Comment: Correct, the current version of kube-aws only deploys a single master, but that wasn't the scope of the question. There is an open issue tracking that work: https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/issues/90.

Comment: Thanks. What are the other advantages of using kube-aws on CoreOS over standard Kubernetes install?

Comment: It sets up all of the AWS resources for you and does it in a reproducible way. All of the TLS assets, the cloudformation output, etc is all stored such that you can audit and version it.

Answer (score 0):

kube-aws deploys both workers and controllers in their own ASG.  Each can be scaled simply by changing the desired min/max on the ASG.  kube-aws does now support multi-master.